# how can i write the test cases for file Uploading through extractRequestContext in akka http services

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Pls suggest here I have an upload service in Akka HTTP micro service it's working fine. now I need to write the test cases for below code

```
    path( "file-upload") {
extractClientIP { ip =>
      optionalHeaderValueByName(Constants.AUTH) { auth =>
        (post & extractRequestContext) {         request =>
               extractRequestContext {
      ctx => {
        implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
        implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
        val currentTime = TimeObject.getCurrentTime()
        fileUpload("fileUpload") {
          case (fileInfo, fileStream) =>
                    val localPath = Configuration.excelFilePath
            val uniqueidString = "12345"
            val filename = uniqueidString + fileInfo.fileName
            val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(localPath) resolve filename)
            val writeResult = fileStream.runWith(sink)
            onSuccess(writeResult) { result =>
              result.status match {
                case Success(_) =>
                  var excelPath = localPath + File.separator + uniqueidString + fileInfo.fileName 
                var doc_count = itemsExcelParse(excelPath, companyCode, subCompanyId, userId) 
                                   val currentTime2 = TimeObject.getCurrentTime()
                                  var upload_time = currentTime2 - currentTime
                  val resp: JsValue = Json.toJson(doc_count)
                  complete {
                    val json: JsValue = Json.obj("status" -> Constants.SUCCESS,
                      "status_details" -> "null", "upload_details" -> resp)
                    HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK, entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`), json.toString))
                  }

                case Failure(e) =>
                  complete {
                                       val json: JsValue = Json.obj("status" -> Constants.ERROR, "status_details" -> Constants.ERROR_445)
                    HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.BandwidthLimitExceeded, entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`), json.toString))
                  }
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried test cases but it's not working

```
          " File upload " should "be able to upload file" in {

    val p: Path = Paths.get("E:\\Excel\\Tables.xlsx")
    val formData = Multipart.FormData.fromPath("fileUpload", ContentTypes.NoContentType, p, 1000)
    Post(s"/file-upload", formData) -> route -> check {
      println(" File upload - file uploaded successfully")
      status shouldBe StatusCodes.OK
      responseAs[String] contains "File successfully uploaded"
    }
  }
```

I have changed content type also into `application/octet-stream`. File not uploaded to the server please suggest here how can I write the test case for file uploading.